# Computing the union of the keySets of two HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I want to compute the union of the keys of two hashmaps. I wrote the following code (MWE below), but I

get UnsupportedOperationException. What would be a good of accomplishing this?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class AddAll {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Map<String, Integer> first = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> second = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        first.put("First", 1);
        second.put("Second", 2);

        Set<String> one = first.keySet();
        Set<String> two = second.keySet();

        Set<String> union = one;
        union.addAll(two);

        System.out.println(union);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, `union` is not a *copy* of `one`, it *is* `one`.  It *is* `first.keySet()`.  And `first.keySet()` isn't a copy of the keys of `first`, [it's a *view*, and won't support adds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29), as documented in `Map.keySet()`.

So you need to actually do a copy.  The simplest way is probably to write

```
 one = new HashSet<String>(first);
```

which uses the "copy constructor" of `HashSet` to do an actual copy, instead of just referring to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the `keySet` is the actual data of the map, it's not a copy.  If it let you call `addAll` there, you'd be dumping all those keys into the first map with no values!  The HashMap purposely only allows you to add new mappings by using the `put` type methods of the actual map.

You want `union` to be an actual new set probably, not the backing data of the first hashmapL

```
    Set<String> one = first.keySet();
    Set<String> two = second.keySet();

    Set<String> union = new HashSet<String>(one);
    union.addAll(two);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code instead

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class AddAll {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Map<String, Integer> first = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> second = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> union = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        first.put("First", 1);
        second.put("Second", 2);
        union.putAll(first);
        union.putAll(second);

        System.out.println(union);
        System.out.println(union.keySet());


    }


}
```